# Le débat trampoline, masculin ou féminin?

Tags: genre

Bonjour, publié hier dans les journaux du Québec, trampoline serait maintenant acceptable dans les deux genres.  Donc terminé les arguments de "un" et pas "une".

Références:

- [Dites-vous un ou une trampoline?](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/v_popr203.asp) et
- [Banque de dépannage linguistique - Trampoline](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3280).

Cet avis est de l'Office québécois de langue française.

Qu'en est-il en France, Belgique, autres pays où on utilise le français?

Answer (score 6):

Pour le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trampoline) *trampoline* est un substantif masculin.

Mais, il est indiqué que pour le Robert 1985, le mot est féminin. Je n'ai pas le Robert 1985 sous la main pour vérifier, mais j'ai celui de 1986 où il est dit que trampoline est masculin !

De mon côté, je suis Parisien, j'ai toujours entendu ce mot employé au masculin.

Voir aussi [L'Oreille tendue](http://oreilletendue.com/2016/09/05/du-temps-ou-loreille-senvoyait-en-lair/)

Comment: 1985, vieux un peu.  L'article de l'OQLF date de 2018, il semble que cette acceptabilité est récente.

Comment: @Nic3500: Je n'ai pas le Robert 1985 sous la main pour vérifier, mais j'ai celui de 1986 où il est dit que trampoline est masculin !

Comment: En effet, l'article de l'OQLF mentionne que la majorité des dictionnaires disent que le mot est masculin, et c'est ce que j'ai toujours lu.  Il semble que c'est plus une question d'usage local qu'une modification du genre du mot.

Comment: Meme remarque pour moi, c'est un nom masculin qui peut je pense de par sa consonnance feminine avoir ete employe au feminin dans certaines regions.